# 200status but collection remains empty

Tags: mongodb, express, postman

I'm trying to get some crud operations on mongodb,

when I get rid of async await I get the 200 code but nothing get saved on db which I guess is normal, with asynchronous code I get the 'no response from  server' error when I test my routes on postman.

/routes.js

```
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
const appointmentController =require ('../controllers/appointments');


router.get('/list',appointmentController.list);
router.post('/add',appointmentController.add);


module.exports = router
```

/controllers.js

```
const Appointment = require("../models/Appointment");

module.exports = {
    list: async (req, res) => {
    const appointment =  await Appointment.find();
    res.send({appointment});
     },
   add: async (req, res) => {
   const appointment = new Appointment(req.body);
   await appointment.save();
   return res.status(200).json('saved to the db !');

  },

 };
```

/model :

```
 const appointmentSchema = new Schema({
 Neurologist: {type: String, required: true},
 Remarks: String,
 Date: { type: Date, required: true },
 Hour: { type: Number, required: true },
 Type: {type: String, required: true}
});
 const Appointment = mongoose.model("appointment", appointmentSchema);
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong, I'm still a newbie, any help would much appreciated!

Comment: can you add the model so we can help?

Comment: @zardilior my bad , I just corrected the file name :-)

Answer (score 1):

the probleme was that when I first put : await appointment.save() it resulted on a server timeout . so this part of code was bugy wich explains why when I got rid of async I  could get code 200 but nothing went to the database. actually the req.body didn't have time to be sent .it is this part of code that should be asynchronous.

```
add: async (req, res) => {
const appointment =  await new Appointment(req.body);
appointment.save();
return res.status(200).json({message:'cool saved to the db !'});
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be an error in your mysql, which is not showing because you are not handling the error, replace the save for:

```
await appointment.save().catch(function(err){ console.log(err)}))
```

And see what it prints. You are also returning "saved to db" without checking if the save was succesful, nor saving it to a variable

Comment: were you able to test this?